# Unknown part of ER model

Tags: mysql, entity-relationship

I want to create this, but I have no idea how it really is. My guess is that maybe it works like a foreign key inside the table Employee, but again , I don't understand how can you create something like this. I am sorry if this is already been answered , but I have no idea how to search it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are right. You need a foreign key inside the employee table, so each employee will be associated to one supervisor.